# com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 16: User disabled the feature. (Firebase Google SignIn)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-oauth

I am trying to learn to implement Firebase Google SignIn in an android app.
The only case it works when a device contains only one(single) google account, and works well.
But when device have multiple google accounts it shows this error :-

```
com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 16: User disabled the feature.
 at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.TaskUtil.setResultOrApiException(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:4)
 at com.google.android.gms.internal.auth-api.zbbc.zbb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth@@20.7.0:1)
 at com.google.android.gms.internal.auth-api.zbab.zba(com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth@@20.7.0:4)
 at com.google.android.gms.internal.auth-api.zbb.onTransact(com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth@@20.7.0:3)
 at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1351)
 at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1310)
```

which seems confusing as if there was any problem in setting up Firebase console then the device containing single google account should also not work but it this case it works fine.

Here is the code snippet :-

```
class GoogleAuthUiClient(
    private val context: Context,
    private val oneTapClient: SignInClient ) {

    private val auth = Firebase.auth

    suspend fun signIn(): IntentSender?{
        val result =  try {
            oneTapClient.beginSignIn(
                buildSignInRequest()
            ).await()
        }catch (e: Exception){
            e.printStackTrace()
            if(e is CancellationException) throw e
            null
        }
        return result?.pendingIntent?.intentSender
    }

    suspend fun signInWithIntent(intent: Intent): SignInResult {
        val credentials = oneTapClient.getSignInCredentialFromIntent(intent)
        val googleIdToken = credentials.googleIdToken
        val googleCredentials = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(googleIdToken,null)
        return try {
            val user = auth.signInWithCredential(googleCredentials).await().user
            SignInResult(
                data = user?.run {
                    UserData( userID = uid,
                    userName = displayName,
                    profilePictureUrl = photoUrl?.toString()
                ) },
                errorMessage = null
            )
        }catch (e: Exception){
            e.printStackTrace()
            if(e is CancellationException) throw e
            SignInResult(null,
                e.message)
        }
    }

    private fun buildSignInRequest(): BeginSignInRequest{
        return BeginSignInRequest.Builder()
            .setGoogleIdTokenRequestOptions(
                GoogleIdTokenRequestOptions.builder()
                    .setSupported(true)
                    .setServerClientId(context.getString(R.string.web_client_id))
                    .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(false)
                    .build())
            .setAutoSelectEnabled(true)
            .build()
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithGoogle).

Comment: @alex-mamo Thank You Sir, For your reply, as mentioned in your resource, it is required to take care of both the cases -previously signedIn and new user which was missing in my code. But Sir still the same error occurred with same error code after searching further online the it came to know that the error was caused by:-       Google Account sign-in prompts which needed to be enabled in the Google Accounts, which was resolved after enabling it.
It can enable these prompts from your Google account's Third-party apps & services settings page: https://myaccount.google.com/connections/settings